# How long will the status "awaiting decision" after minor revisions last?

Tags: publications

I submit my manuscript to IEEE WCL on 4/14/2019 (Minor revision). On 4/26, the status on ScholarOne changed to awaiting decision. But until now, 5/17, the status are still "awaiting decision". I want to know how long will this status last. Can I send a email to AE?

Comment: It will last until the people who have to make the decision have actually made it.  We don't have any way of guessing how long that might take them.

Comment: "It's tough to make predictions, especially about the future." (Yogi Berra, probably)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize the comments: **as long as it takes**.  The AE is not solely employed by IEEE, but also has a faculty position (usually) and other obligations.  Although it's frustrating, your manuscript is probably one of many they are responsible for and they have their own stuff going on.  Don't email them. They know they have to make the decision, and your email will not make them do so any faster.  Unfortunately, you will just have to wait it out.

Comment: Don’t entail them *unless you have a pressing deadline* related to the paper (graduation, tenure packet, etc). Most AE would be okay to get an email if you had a specific reason rather than your own impatience.

Comment: Thank you for the answering the question and it is very useful. But I am sorry that I clicked the answer useless button due to operational errors.